# Postgres - How to aggregate json rows into a single json object

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, jsonb

I have this rows of  json like so:

```
1. {"0": 2}
2. {"2": 0}
3. {"3": 0}
4. {"4": 1}
5. {"13": 0}
```

How to convert it into a single object?

```
{
  "0": 2,
  "2": 0,
  "3": 0,
  "4": 1,
  "13": 0
}
```

I tried experimenting with jsonb_agg but not working

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `jsonb_each` to split object into a set of key/value pairs. and `jsonb_object_agg` to returns the aggregated key–value pairs as a jsonb object :

```
select jsonb_object_agg(c.key, c.value) as myJson
FROM mytable, jsonb_each(myjson) as c
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7TYBflyW)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest is to define an aggregate that does this:

```
create aggregate jsonb_concat_agg(jsonb) 
(
  sfunc = jsonb_concat(jsonb, jsonb),
  stype = jsonb
);
```

Then you can do:

```
select jsonb_concat_agg(the_column)
from the_table;
```